# Game Center Turn-Based Auto Match is not Working

Tags: game-center, gamekit

I'm using the Standard Matchmaking User Interface and two iPads iOS6. The problem is when I create a new match in the first device, the second device supposed to see the existing match when I view the Matchmaking User Interface but it's not. I'm sure my code is correct. here is the method:

```
-(void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController*)viewController {

    // the view that will present Matchmaker View Controller
    self.viewCaller = viewController;

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

    GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *viewMatchmaker = [[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
    viewMatchmaker.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;
    viewMatchmaker.showExistingMatches = YES;
    [self.viewCaller presentViewController:viewMatchmaker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I even tried on two different sample games but the same problem, so how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Gamekit does matchmaker for a turnbase match it is trying to find a match with an open slot to fill the player in. If it cannot find an open slot to fill the player in it then creates a new match.

Try on one device to create a match and go through one turn with that device, that is when you call...

```
 endTurnWithNextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler:
```

Then on the other device try looking for a match.

Comment: yes that's right. even when I invited a friend.. the notification would not appear to him unless I end turn. I tried with 3 players match and I invited 2 friends. the first player should end turn so that the notification appears to the second player. and when the second player end turn, the notification will appear to the third player. this is weird.